# How tcp works in container, is port hijack possible

Tags: docker, containers

I need to understand how TCP uses ephemeral port in a container. I understand network is namespaced, and TCP port in container would be NAT’d to host port. Does that mean for two containers running in the same host, if one container binds to 64000 ports(use up 64k ports available inside the container using TCP bind(), without binding to host port), the other container won’t be able to use any port as all ports in the host system are used up?

Assuming one IP per host ofcourse

Answer (score 1):

Hi TheJoker if you'll try to use localhost docker engine and run two containers with port let's say 80 with simple nginx server you can run them without any problem as long as you are not binding them with host port. If you are binding port 80 of container with port 80 of host obviously you can do that only for one container.
If you will run this command twice

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
```

You'll receive similar message to this one

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint angry_mclean (d8bbf5af6503b4d54d234f1bf69ee372a8ada6ef07a5ebd138479691d5679994): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated.
```

To sum up you can run as many containers as you want with exposed port but you can bind only one to host port.

If you'll run container with 64000 ports bind to your host (-P option to bind all exposed ports) than your container is occupying all ports (not possible as your host system use some ports but theoretically).

UPDATE:
For more information please see :
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose
https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/

Comment: Suppose you don’t bind with the host port, then inside the container if you bind to 64000 ports how does NAT work? It needs to select 64000 ports in host as well which means a second container cannot bind (from inside) to a port right

Comment: By bind I meant binding to a port for opening tcp connection inside the container

Comment: For example in LDAP protocol client does TCP bind(), in that case if one container used up all 64k ports inside it would a second container be able to make LDAP request

Comment: Docker is creating a private subnet for your container which is namespaced so you can treat containers as regular "VM" or separate host. You can check it by running docker inspect name_of_container

Comment: Ok sure, In case of TCP connect() a node port is NAT’d with the subnet port of container. What happens when you bind and connect?

Comment: Well you have a detailed information here https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/ - this is pretty much OS dependent question as on Linux host we are talking about iptables while on Windows about something else. Also as a starting point https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose.